# Point chart plot on existing line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to show a moving point (image) with X,Y coordinates and theeta angle (only to rotate the object) on an existing line charts using Google chart. 
Please suggest me as I am new in integrating Google chart.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks but actually i want to plot two graph one is line chart and other is point chart which will be move on line chart

Comment: sounds like you need `ComboChart`, you can have multiple series types, such as scatter and line...